# Self referential data

Tags: induction, inductive-datatypes

Can anyone show me step by step how to do a proof on self referential structures.

For example, this example is in scala

```
lazy val y : Stream[Int] = 1 #:: (y map (_ + 1))
```

How do I prove that y is a stream of natural numbers. #:: is stream cons in scala.

Also this example is from wikipedia

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

How do I prove fibs is a stream of fibonacci numbers.

I'd really appreciate if someone over here can spell out a nice detailed proof step by step for me. I don't really see how to apply inductive reasoning to any of the above.

Comment: Induction might not work, you'll need coinduction/bisimulation to handle the infinite data I would think?